# How to parse html code to get image src

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have html code in which image tag is used.. I want to get the src of image ..

One idea is that...i split that code :

```
var temp=htmlContent.split("<img src='")[1];
var imageURL=temp.split("'")[0];
```

but There is no gurantee that src would be the first attribute of img tag....like this

```
 <img alt="image" src="url"/>
```

So please give me some feasible solution for Google Apps Script

Comment: your prefered language for this parsing?

Answer (score 1):

```
// parses implicitly as "<html><body><img alt='alt' src='source!'></body></html>"
Xml.parse("<img alt='alt' src='source!'>", true).getElement() 
    .getElements()[0]  // descend into <html>
    .getElements()[0]  // descend into <body>
    .getAttribute('src').getValue();  // get the value of the 'src' attribute
```

To explain, `Xml.parse` with the second param as true parses the text as a lenient HTML document. It implicitly adds an `<html>` tag and a `<body>` tag which you need to descend into with the `.getElements()[0].getElements()[0]` calls. Then you are at the `<img>` tag and you can examine its `src` attribute without worrying about where it is in the tag.

Comment: You passed ""<img alt='alt' src='source!'>"" as argument to Xml.parse(). But the fight is to extract this img tag portion from html content.After that i can perform above code

Comment: You can pass in whatever you like and examine it via the Xml methods. This was a simple example.

Comment: Ya, you are right...But the problem is that we don't know that at which hierarchy level <img> tag exists ??..This solution is valid if we have have <img> tag then we can parse as above...but if we have full html code then to determine the hierarchy level of <img> tag could create problemm..For this, I used the split method to extract <img> tag and then we can parse...

Comment: You don't need to know the hierarchy. You can explore it programmatically.